# OSGi background thread failure

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi

What should be done when a `BundleActivator` runs a background thread, and that background thread has an unrecoverable error?

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator
{
   private Thread t;
   @Override
   public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception
   {
      t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
             public void run(){
                while (!Thread.interrupted()){
                  // do something which may throw a runtime exception
               }
            }
         });
      t.start();
   }
   @Override void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception
   {
      t.interrupt();
      t.join();
   }
}
```

With this example, how can I notify the OSGi framework that the thread is dead and the bundle is effectively stopped and not running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how Peter Kriens performs similar actions in [this article](http://www.aqute.biz/Snippets/Stop).  All you would need to do with his example is invoke the stop on the activator in his catch block, instead of doing the printStackTrace.

Comment: The comments on this page were made back in 2007, and suggested further future discussion. Is there no newer information?

Comment: Seems the link is dead. I found this [one](http://blog.osgi.org/2007/07/best-practice-with-depressed-bundles.h‌​tml) which seems close to the original one.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing to do is just log the error, preferably to the OSGi Log Service. Then an administrator can detect the problem with the bundle and decide what to do. You should implement this as a Declarative Services component rather than as a `BundleActivator`, because that will give you much easier access to the Log Service, and you will also be able to have more than one of these things in your bundle.

I don't think that the bundle should attempt to stop itself. This puts the bundle in a weird state.... it's stopped but still has code running... i.e. the code that called `stop()`. This may be only for a brief period but it feels wrong.

A bundle that's in the ACTIVE state doesn't necessarily have to be "doing something" all the time, it just has the *potential* to "do something". The fact that something failed shouldn't really affect the external state of the bundle.

Comment: Wouldn't a bundle, listed as "ACTIVE", but in a failed state be a weird state as well? The example is actually a monitoring thread in production which is reading from a serial port and relaying messages. This is not something that, to my knowledge, can be done as a Declarative Service.

Comment: No I don't think so. That's a misunderstanding of what the ACTIVE state of a bundle implies. And yes you can do this as a DS component.... DS components can do *anything* (and more) that a `BundleActivator` can do.

Comment: I cannot find any clear documentation on DS and how it works online. Do you have any pointers? My understanding was DS was for provide and consuming services only. Additionally, what then is the difference between ACTIVE and RESOLVED? I was under the assumption that ACTIVE was meant to represent that whatever the bundle provided or did was actually being provided or done.

Comment: The DS specification is fairly clear, otherwise try the book "OSGi in Action". DS does indeed allow you to provide and consume services, but a DS component can also have activate/deactivate methods, just like `BundleActivator`. This is why I said that DS components can do anything a `BundleActivator` can do, and more besides.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question... as I said, the ACTIVE state indicates the *potential* for the bundle to be doing something, not a *guarantee* that it is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, OSGi cannot directly help you in this particular situation. I usually rely on [uncaught exception handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) to get notified of thread crashes or I implement some form of SW watchdog.

The point is that a bundle that spawns multiple threads and sucessfully completes its start method remains ACTIVE even if one of these threads crashes after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Neil is (as usual) very right. A bundle should never stop itself since that interferes with the management agent. The start/stop is the message from this management agent to a bundle to say that it should be active. If the bundle cannot perform its responsibility you should log the message, wait a bit (increasingly longer) and retry.

The log is the place to notify, stopping a bundle is mixing levels badly.

Comment: What I am attempting is beyond notification, but rather automated recovery. Since this is not a published service, but rather a daemon thread, I am not sure how a "retry" would work. Does this also mean that your article  @ http://www.aqute.biz/Snippets/Stop is no longer valid, or is valid in other circumstances.

Comment: The snippet is just there to show that you CAN do it but it by no means suggests you do it. 
A daemon usually fails because there are transient problems. E.g. the internet is down. Just keep logging, wait a bit, and retry. The computer cannot do much else anyway.

Comment: If the error state is recoverable or retryable, then the thread itself should try to recover or retry. If not (or if the retries repeatedly fail as well) then ultimately a human operator **has to** intervene. The Log Service is the standard way for the bundle to send a notification to the operator.

Comment: Thank you both for your time. I am trying to make my service as bullet proof as possible. My expectation was that the bundle state could somehow be used to give an indication at the the health of a bundle. My reasoning was that when a bundles health became jeopardized, I could alert the runtime or unload the bundle to reflect the health problem. It seems from this conversation that the best I can hope for it to keep background thread alive in predictable states, and possible System.exit(1) upon unexpected thread death?

Comment: Never, never, never do System.exit ... The OSGi spec clearly separates the responsibility for the management of the system out of the responsibility of the (hopefully) reusable parts. If you do System.exit or stop your bundle you get an unreusable component since it cannot be mamaged anymore. Cohesion ... only do the thing you're responsible for. Highly cohesive systems allow many combinations, combining makes you have to write the same functionality in many variants.